# Friendlier/Custom Errors in Chai.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bdd, chai

I'm using the [chai.js](http://chaijs.com/) assertion library to find possible errors in manifests created by semi-technical professionals. In other words, configurations are being written but human error is *highly* likely.

Currently, a failing assertion like this:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

expect('String', 'Should be a Number').to.be.a('number');
```

Results in an error being thrown and the full stack showing up. Can I reduce the bloat by instructing the error not to be thrown, while outputting a smaller, more contextual message to console?

In terms of the stack trace, I have tried this, without any success:

```
chai.config.includeStack = false;
```

Disclaimer: this is my first attempt at using the [chai.js](http://chaijs.com/) library.

Answer (score 1):

`expect` throws an error when it fails, so you could wrap each call in a try/catch and just consume the parts you want:

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;

function friendlyAssert (test) {
  try { test() }
  catch (e) { console.log(e.message); }
}

// logs a message
friendlyAssert(function () {
  expect("string", "Should be a number").to.be.a("number");
});

// completes silently
friendlyAssert(function () {
  expect(8, "Should be a number").to.be.a("number");
})

// output:
// Should be a number: expected 'string' to be a number
```

Comment: I did try this originally but the thing I don't like about it is that it requires syntactic bloat for one assertion (i.e having to wrap each assertion in the method call with an anonymous function). So far, I've not found anything in the chai API that will allow me to suppress  errors - so this may be my only option. I was hoping there might be an event-emitter within the API where I could listen for errors and choose to ignore them or change the output. I'll give it a few days and mark this as correct if nothing else surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to take this route, but you can create a Chai plugin that overwrites `a/an` with an implementation that catches errors and just displays them instead of throwing an exception.

For instance:

```
var chai   = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;

chai.use(function(_chai, utils) {
  function newImpl(_super) {
    return function () {
      var r = _super.apply(this, arguments);
      return function() {
        try {
          return r.apply(this, arguments);
        } catch(e) {
          console.log(e.message);
        }
      };
    }
  };
  [ 'a', 'an' ].forEach((prop) => {
    _chai.Assertion.overwriteProperty(prop,  newImpl);
  });
});

expect('String', 'Should be a Number').to.be.a('string');
```

You'd need to overwrite all methods and properties that you use in your tests (the code above only handles `a/an`, which are both a property and a method, so the implementation shown is pretty specific for those).

More info [here](http://chaijs.com/guide/helpers/).